# How to set values dynamically using knockout

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, knockout.js

I want to show datas retrieved from database in a form and I am using spring MVC in my project.
I know in knockout to set a value in input textfield we use like

```
ko.observable("somevalue");
```

for example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/LkqTU/16171/)

and but we are assiging this *somevalue* in javascript code.My values are retrived from server and to show data I used

```
<input class="span8" type="text" data-bind="value: name" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" name="name" value="${currentpatient.user.name}">
```

but in this way the data is not getting printed.So can any body please tell me how to dynamic values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My values are retrived from server and to show data I used but in this way the data is not getting printed

For example your server returned a `User` instance that has properties such as: `firstName` and `lastName`,

then to access these properties you do in jsp like:

- to get firstName: `${user.firstName}`.
- same to get lastName: `${user.lastName}`.

to get access inside knockout.js do like:

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('${user.firstName}');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('${user.lastName}');
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```